# How to disable procps-ng 3.3.10 free wide output format?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora

I'm writing a script that is supposed to simply tell me the amount of free physical memory excluding caches and I noticed that my Fedora system shows a different output format than a CentOS system I have a Unix account on:

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7865868     3934924      241300      485916     3689644     3093784
Swap:       8388604      950988     7437616
$ ssh -q centos free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1921876    1848024      73852          0      10120      87124
-/+ buffers/cache:    1750780     171096
Swap:      2097148     240428    1856720
$ free -V                           
free from procps-ng 3.3.10
$ ssh -q centos free -V
procps version 3.2.8
```

Is there a way I make my Fedora `free` output look like the CentOS one?

Comment: Does the `-o/--old` option help?

Comment: @jofel: it would, but my `free` doesn't seem to have one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Note that it is not just a matter of formatting. The `free` program in procps-ng has been recently updated to include the new `MemAvailable` metric that was recently introduced in the Linux kernel and that is a much better indication of the memory actually available than the typical (and often wrong) "free + buffers/cache" estimation (see below).

The `free` program included in procps-ng 3.3.10 does not provide any option to disable this info. And in fact what you are looking at is already the "condensed" format. There is a "wide" option as well (try `-w` or `--wide`) which does not aggregate buffers and cache.

If you are writing a script to find out available memory, I would suggest to use the "available" value reported by free, instead of "free + buffers/cache". See [this comment](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34e431b0ae398fc54ea69ff85ec700722c9da773) on the Linux Kernel mailing list which explains why `MemAvailable` was introduced:

> Many load balancing and workload placing programs check /proc/meminfo to
>   estimate how much free memory is available.  They generally do this by
>   adding up "free" and "cached", which was fine ten years ago, but is
>   pretty much guaranteed to be wrong today.
>
> It is wrong because Cached includes memory that is not freeable as page
>   cache, for example shared memory segments, tmpfs, and ramfs, and it does
>   not include reclaimable slab memory, which can take up a large fraction
>   of system memory on mostly idle systems with lots of files.